# POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting an POST 500 (Internal Server Error) on my website.

When testing on my local host i get no errors, only after publishing and running the site live do i get errors when trying to call my stored procedure.

The line number has pointed me to the line of code below in my Jquery File:

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

Here is the ajax call it fails on:

```
$.post("SaveSellGoods", { goodsId: goodsId, price: price, customerId: customerId }, function () {
});
```

I have checked and all the variables have the correct values.

Here is where it should move to, but i don't think it ever gets here:

```
public void SaveSellGoods(string goodsId, decimal price, int customerId)
{
  DBH.GoodsStatusUpdate(int.Parse(goodsId), 3);
  DBH.TransactionInsert(price, 2, int.Parse(Session["employeeId"].ToString()), int.Parse(goodsId), customerId);
}
```

I get this error across all browsers and i'm not sure what the cause is.

Could someone please tell me what it is i'm doing wrong or missing, or someway to get more information on this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you look at the exception being returned using the developer tools in your browser, or using a exception logger like ELMAH (if .NET)?

Comment: jQuery can't throw Internal Server Error, the problem lies on the server side.

Comment: This problem is occuring at server level, im sure  its not allowing certain request. You should check the server logs too see which request is causing the problem.

Comment: Do you have attributes (decorators) on the c# method?

Comment: @StevenV Thanks, i will look to set this up now and try get back with some more information.

Comment: make sure your live and local deployments are actually the same... including databases and addresses of connections etc. whenever I get a problem like this the solution is often me forgetting to carry over some change I've made to the local server config or database, or I'm referencing the database with my local server's IP instead of the live IP or FQDN.

Comment: also what server side language are you using? java?

Comment: @jammypeach I am developing in C#, I am sure that the live and local deployment are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem at the end was with the parameters being the incorrect type.

Adding parse float to my price parameter fixed the problem.

```
parseFloat()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the key  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] at your action method. hope it will work